# What is the determinant of special matrix, diagonal elements are i.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a problem.
To find and prove the formula for $det(A)$ of given matrix of size $n\times n$:

$a_{i,j}=2, i\neq j$, and $a_{i,i}=i$

So for example:

$det\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&2&2\\
2&2&2&2\\
2&2&3&2\\
2&2&2&4\\
\end{pmatrix}=-4
$

What is the most straight-forward way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the solution myself in the end, quite simple task to be honest when I got the idea. By doing the row operations, so by eliminating twos from 3rd to n-th row simply by subtracting 2nd row result matrix is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&2&2&...&2\\
2&2&2&2&...&2\\
0&0&1&0&...&0\\
0&0&0&2&...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&...&n-2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then eliminate 1st item on 2nd row, the result is now:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&2&2&...&2\\
0&-2&-2&-2&...&-2\\
0&0&1&0&...&0\\
0&0&0&2&...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&...&n-2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix is now upper triangular, so we simply multiply the diagonal.

And result can be interpreted as:

$det(A)=1\space for\space n=1;\\det(A)=-2\cdot(n-2!)\space for\space n>1;n\in\mathbb{N}$